# Demo environment and data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application running in which people can enter timesheets, get reports, ...: www.temponia.com

Now I would like to create a demo environment where users can experiment without the need of having to register.

I already found the gems faker and forgery to generate demo data.  But my question is: when a user starts the demo environment, should I generate the data and write the data to the database?  I don't want all users to share the same demo environment since one user can completely destroy the experience for other testers...

When I write it to the database, and delete it after a couple of days, aren't I running the risk that some tables will get really high identity values really quick?  I would generate for example several thousand timesheet entries to make it look realistic...

Are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: I see you have a nice demo set in place. Would you mind sharing how did you solve it? How is demo data being modified and how it is kept current?

Comment: Hi, sure.  I create all the demo data on the fly.  This takes less than 10 seconds so I do it live when a user starts a demo.  After a few weeks of inactivity all data that was generated is erased automatically by a daily tasks that checks this.
Most time went into the generation of good demo data.

Comment: Thanks. We have a perhaps more difficult set of demo data required (project management & co) so I expect it to be very hard to keep it up to date completely programmatically. We can use a "template" user, but we have issues with keeping the "dates" current. I suppose that's not an issue in your case, right?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should let the users do what they want to do, to show the completeness of the application, and let everyone share the same environment.

To repopulate your application, you can add some task every X minutes (depends of frequentation), to automatically insert data when it reaches a minimum threshold. See for example `whenever` gem to add commands in `crontab`.

https://github.com/javan/whenever